# POSTGRES multiple to one constraint

Tags: postgresql

I have two colums, foo and bar.  foo can only exist with one bar, but can exists n times.  If I try to insert foo with a different value of bar, it needs to fail.

```
 foo | bar
----------
  a  |  a
  a  |  a
  b  |  a
  b  |  a
  b  |  b  <---  this needs to fail.
```

How can I solve this?

And somewhat tangentially what is the proper language for this question?

Comment: Perhaps you should normalize your table rather than creating a contraint

Answer (score 3):

You can use an `EXCLUDE` constraint.
Using the extension `btree_gist`:

```
CREATE EXTENSION btree_gist;
```

You can define a table

```
CREATE TABLE fb (
  foo text,
  bar text,
  EXCLUDE USING gist (foo WITH =, bar WITH <>)
);
```

such that the following insertion is ok:

```
#= INSERT INTO fb VALUES ('a', 'a'), ('a', 'a'), ('b', 'b');
INSERT 0 3
Time: 1,392 ms
#= SELECT * FROM fb;
┌─────┬─────┐
│ foo │ bar │
├─────┼─────┤
│ a   │ a   │
│ a   │ a   │
│ b   │ b   │
└─────┴─────┘
(3 rows)
```

but inserting the `('b', 'a')` tuple fails because `'b'` already has a `bar = 'b'` row.

```
#= INSERT INTO fb VALUES ('b', 'a');
ERROR:  23P01: conflicting key value violates exclusion constraint "fb_foo_bar_excl"
DETAIL:  Key (foo, bar)=(b, a) conflicts with existing key (foo, bar)=(b, b).
SCHEMA NAME:  public
TABLE NAME:  fb
CONSTRAINT NAME:  fb_foo_bar_excl
```

---

**Edit**: Though this works I agree with Conrad Frix's comment, normalizing your table is probably a way better idea.

Comment: Thanks!!  This is a hot fix to the database.  I'll probably normalize the database at next code release.  Depends greatly on the performance (and priority of course.)